# NPOI creating excel with SXSSFWorkbook - error on opening

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-core, apache-poi, npoi

I just want to stream a xlsx file using NPOI SXSSF method. But when I download streamed excel file in opening pops up message:

> Excel found unreadable content in 'MyExcelFile.xlsx'. Do you want to
>   recover the contents of the workbook? If you trust the source of this
>   workbook, click Yes.

My code:

```
Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyExce.xlsx\"");
Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "octet-stream");


SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("FirstSheet");

IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);
cell.SetCellValue("firstCell");

//Write file to output stream
wb.Write(Response.Body);
wb.Close();
Response.Body.Flush();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

For `wb.Write(Response.Body)`, it will dispose the Stream after `wb.Write` and `Response.Body` will be broken.

Try code below, to save the stream and write the saved stream to body.

```
public void DownloadFile()
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"MyExce.xlsx\"");
        Response.Headers.Add("Content-type", "octet-stream");

        SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
        SXSSFSheet sheet = (SXSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("FirstSheet");

        IRow row = sheet.CreateRow(0);
        ICell cell = row.CreateCell(0);
        cell.SetCellValue("firstCell");

        //Write file to output stream
        wb.Write(stream);
        var byteArray = stream.ToArray();
        ms.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        ms.WriteTo(Response.Body);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks good but I want to stream excel file that has more than 500 000 rows and I have problems with ram memory.. that's why I don't want to hold the file in ram memory. Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: @OndraStarenko You may consider consulting `NPOI` developer in the github by submitting issues.